# Fill Div Height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I write a html code like this:

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.divs {
    width: 45%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;  
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="divs">
        cell 1<br />
        more information
    </div>
    <div class="divs">
        cell2
    </div>
    <div class="divs">
        cell 3<br />
        more information
    </div>
    <div class="divs">
        cell 4
    </div>
</div>
```

In my code, some of my cells has information and others doesn't have. i want to fill gape between cell 1 and cell 4. How can i fill this gap?

Note: my cells is dynamic and I don't know about count and information.

Comment: Do you want it to look like a table ?

Comment: Use something like https://masonry.desandro.com/ if you wish to have different heights for different divs. Otherwise I would recommend that you go for having same height mentioned in css for all the divs

Comment: Whats your aim? Define what's the end result you want to get !!
You have written them as "cells" and then declared the width of individual div as 45%. This means that only 2 divs at maximum will appear side by side and the others will wrap around to next lines. Using a float further gets them out of normal layout flow. Be Specific

Comment: @KiranDash i agree with the masonry but giving height is not a good approach, see my answer below to use display inline block and vertical align top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***A CSS Solution with your own code***

I think you will be interested in using [**flex**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), It will solve your issue.

**Updated**

**Note:** This doesn't work for **IE9** [if you have a concern in this use up 
use [**modernizr**](https://modernizr.com/docs/#flexbox) to detect whether flex capabilities are present, and provide fallback styles where necessary. ] from IE10 it is supported.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.divs {
    width: 45%;
    border: 1px solid black;  
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="divs">
        cell 1<br />
        more information
    </div>
    <div class="divs">
        cell2
    </div>
    <div class="divs">
        cell 3<br />
        more information
    </div>
    <div class="divs">
        cell 4
    </div>
<div class="divs">
        cell 3<br />
        more information
    </div>
<div class="divs">
        cell 3<br />
        more information
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is, but if you want you can use modernizr to detect whether flex capabilities are present, and provide fallback styles where necessary. Modernizr will add classes like `flexbox`, `no-flexbox`, and` flexbox-legacy` to the HTML element. But it is been supported from IE10 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

> Get max height of `divs` and set for all `div`s.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxHei = 0;
    $('.divs').each(function(){
        if(maxHei<$(this).height())
            maxHei = $(this).height();
    })
    $('.divs').css('height',maxHei);
})
```

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.divs {
    width: 45%;
    border: 1px solid black;  
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="divs">cell 1<br />more information</div>
    <div class="divs">cell2</div>
    <div class="divs">cell 3<br />more information</div>
    <div class="divs">cell 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fill the gap there are two options:

1: You can use [masonry js](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

2: use the below code

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

.divs {
    width: 45%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="divs">
        cell 1<br />
        more information
    </div>
    <div class="divs">
        cell2
    </div>
    <div class="divs">
        cell 3<br />
        more information
    </div>
    <div class="divs">
        cell 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use display: inline-block instead of float: left.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.divs {
    width: 45%;
    border: 1px solid black;  
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="divs">
        cell 1<br />
        more information
    </div>
    <div class="divs">
        cell2
    </div>
    <div class="divs">
        cell 3<br />
        more information
    </div>
    <div class="divs">
        cell 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use tables for i. It is a good option. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/anmolsandal/jxoxejxL/)

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>test <br/>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Css

```
table {
 width:100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr{
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:last-child
{
 border-bottom:0;
}
table tr td {
 border-right: 1px solid black;
}
table tr td:last-child
{
 border-right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this script. It will take height for each div and will update biggest one.

```
  $height = 0;
  $('.divs').each(function(){
  console.log($(this));
   if($(this).height()>$height) { 
     $height = $(this).height();
   }
  }); 
  $('.divs').height($height);
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could do it like this

```
    html, body {

        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
    div#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
div#wrapper .divs {
width: 45%;
height: inherit !important;
border: 1px solid black;  
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do one of the options:

- height in vh instead of %. You could also set min-height or max-height
- in #wrapper, display:flex

Answer (score -1):

Flexbox could be extremely useful in this case, just using the [flex-wrap rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap). You only need to slightly modify your CSS:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.divs {
 flex: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" >
    <div class="divs">
        cell 1<br />
        more information
    </div>
    <div class="divs">
        cell2
    </div>
    <div class="divs">
        cell 3<br />
        more information
    </div>
    <div class="divs">
        cell 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Flexbox to the rescue ;)